# Custom cell label returns nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a tableview, and i have loaded custom cells to it.

However, the cell components doesn't get displayed. (the label returns nil - see image below)

[image]

I have created so many tableview and have has custom cells embedded to it in the past. However, i am having a issue where i am not able to find the solution.

The code is as follows:

cell for row at index path

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";

    MyCell *cell = (MyCell *) [tableView  dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[MyCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle   reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    }



    cell.myLabel.text = @"fhjfhjdhfjdfhd ";

    return cell;
```

Custom cell .h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>



@interface MyCell : UITableViewCell{



}

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel * myLabel;




@end
```

Custom cell .m file

```
#import "MyCell.h"



@implementation MyCell

@synthesize myLabel;



- (void)awakeFromNib {

    // Initialization code

}



- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {

    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];



    // Configure the view for the selected state

}

@end
```

Storyboard

[image]

[image]

Update

There's a project https://github.com/honcheng/PaperFold-for-iOS

On the sidebar there's a tableview that appears when swiped.

that's the tableview where it doesn't display any custom label components.

Wonder if this information will help find the problem.

Comment: I think you should retain the label while declaring property, change weak to strong

Comment: also what is LeftCell  in MyCell *cell = (LeftCell *) [tableView  dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier]; ?

Comment: You didn't register the class did you?

Comment: @SanjayMohnani, weak is fine for IBOutlets since the view (a label in this case) is retained by its superview.

Comment: Tableview give cell identifier name

Comment: how to give cell identifier name from tableview ? did you mean from cell ?

Comment: There is a possibility that you are getting nil from `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` and therefore you are creating a new cell in if block which does not have any label.

Comment: @Krishna Yes, cell after executing that line is `nil`. What should i do ?

Comment: Is it the right identifier used in the IB inspector. @"cell"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use below code

```
   if (cell == nil) {

        NSArray *nib=[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"YourCustomCellName" owner:self options:nil];
        cell=[nib objectAtIndex:0];  //index of your custom cell
    }
```

Note:Please also check your custom cell is allocated memory before assign string to that label. And your custom cell is connected to "custom class"(it have 3rd column in right side inspector)

Please refer attached screen shot.

[image]

Comment: where's the screenshot. i think you forgot to attach it

Comment: i have added the custom cell class. But how can i allocate memory ?

Comment: memory is automatically allocated when you assign nib file

Comment: cell=[nib objectAtIndex:0];

Comment: check break point in your label and check whether cell and label is allocated memory or not. Thanks.

Comment: can you show me your full cellforrowatindexclass method, coz mine is messed up after trying so many suggestions

Comment: It actually crashes at `NSArray *nib= ....` it says its not able to find NIB `MyCell`

Comment: PATableviewCell *cell = (PATableviewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"customCell"];
    
    if (cell == nil) {
        
        NSArray *nib=[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:IS_IPAD ? @"PATableviewCell~ipad":@"PATableviewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:10];
        cell.segmentControl.frame=CGRectMake(cell.segmentControl.frame.origin.x,cell.segmentControl.frame.origin.y,IS_IPAD ?115:60,IS_IPAD ?60:35);
    }
  cell.textPrice.text = @"";

Comment: does this (PATableviewCell) have to be (PATableviewCell *) ?

Comment: Please confirm your "label" reference is connected with "file owner" or "customcell".

Comment: If suppose your "label" is connected with "fileowner" Please remove that reference and connected to "custom cell". Thanks

Comment: its connected with `cell`

Comment: PATableviewCell is my customcell class name

Comment: your will use your custom class name for that place(PATableviewCell)

Comment: are you missing the `*` by any chance `PATableviewCell *cell = (PATableviewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"customCell"];`

Comment: sorry i can't get.Please explain in detail.

Comment: In your code you have not put the `*` before `cell` and after  `PATableviewCell `

Comment: sorry we must need * before cell...sorry..sorry

Comment: I have updated my post with more information. See original question above.

Answer (score 3):

If you have created your Custom Cell using xib, then you need to load that nib while creating cell as-

```
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cellIdentifier";
CustomCell *cell = nil;
        cell = (CustomCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        if(cell == nil)
        {
            cell = (CustomCell *)[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil] lastObject];

        }

[cell.label setText:@"label text"];
```

Comment: i have created using storyboard. is it the same ?

Answer (score 0):

try this one,
set tag for your label then

```
UILabel *lblName=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
lblName=(UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:5];
```

than assign your value to label

Comment: have you assigned class for the cell as MyCell in storyboard?

Answer (score 0):

If you use storyboard to customize your cell.

You don't need to alloc cell in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:

Use like this

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MyCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    return cell;
}
```

[image]

Comment: you want me to remove the `cell==nil` condition and add only the code you gave above ? it crashes then. says `UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

Comment: Did you set Identifier for your cell?

Comment: I have updated my post with more information. See original question above.

Comment: I think there's another problem in my code. I have added a github project and the custom cell doesn't get added there. See post above. Thanks.